# 64bit packages being removed when installing Skype/Teamviewer

Tags: skype, vlc, qt

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 and when I try to install skype I get the expected message about missing dependencies and when i run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I get this

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lib32asound2 lib32z1 libc6-i386
  Suggested packages:
  lib32asound2-plugins
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdbusmenu-qt2 libphonon4 libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 musique phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer python-qt4 qt-at-spi retext sni-qt sqlitebrowser
  teamviewer virtualbox-4.3 vlc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lib32asound2 lib32z1 libc6-i386
```

That removes my **vlc, musique and bunch of other qt stuff**
I know I did something wrong along the way. But what?
Thanks

Comment: Try just running `sudo apt-get install lib32asound2* lib32z1 libc6-i386`. Please refer to what instructions you are using :-)

Comment: You have a `Suggested package` in your error message, lib32asound2-plugins, that has this bug report: [lib32asound-plugins removes Skype and Wine apps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-plugins/+bug/376493).

Answer (score 0):

Try just running `sudo apt-get install lib32asound2* lib32z1 libc6-i386`. That should clear up any dependices, which it what the `-f` command is mean to do - to quote a man page:

> **-f, --fix-broken**
>       Fix. Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any
>   packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. Any package(s)
>   that are specified must completely correct the problem. This option is
>   sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself
>   does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is
>   possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to
>   require manual intervention. Use of this option together with -m may
>   produce an error in some situations.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get